# How to group and count objects by property in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list with objects like this:

```
class Visit:
    def __init__(self):
        self.date = ''
        self.diagnosis=''
        self.doctor=''
        self.price=0
```

I need group objects by two fields - `diagnosis` and `doctor`, and then counting their.

From this:

```
list = [Visit(date = '2014-05-24',diagnosis='Z00', doctor='Smith', price=0),
        Visit(date = '2014-05-25',diagnosis='Z00', doctor='Smith', price=0),
        Visit(date = '2014-05-15',diagnosis='Z00', doctor='Smith', price=0),
        Visit(date = '2014-05-24',diagnosis='K40', doctor='Smith', price=0),
        Visit(date = '2014-05-20',diagnosis='K40', doctor='Smith', price=0),
        Visit(date = '2014-05-27',diagnosis='K40', doctor='Jakobs', price=0),
        Visit(date = '2014-05-21',diagnosis='J00', doctor='Abrams', price=0),
        Visit(date = '2014-05-22',diagnosis='J00', doctor='Abrams', price=0),
```

I need get something like this:

```
{ 3 : {'doctor':'Smith','diagnosis':'Z00'},     
  2 : {'doctor':'Smith','diagnosis':'K40'}, 
  1 : {'doctor':'Jakobs','diagnosis':'K40'},
  2 : {'doctor':'Abrams','diagnosis':'J00'}}
```

In the future this may be more fields. I have to count how many times a person has visited the same doctor with the same diagnosis. Thanks.

Comment: `for i, visit in enumerate(list_of_visits): result_dict[i] = {'doctor': visit.doctor, 'diagnosis': visit.diagnosis}`? It's hard to work backwards from your example output because we can only guess where each value comes from.

Comment: Then counting their what, exactly? What do the numbers in the output dictionary keys signify?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist, i add additional details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you are asking to count how many times a given doctor issued a specific diagnosis. In this case, `Counter` from `collections` can prove handy:

```
from collections import Counter

class Visit:
    def __init__(self):
        self.date = ''
        self.diagnosis=''
        self.doctor=''
        self.price=0

visits = [Visit() for _ in xrange(10)]

# tuples = [(visit.doctor, visit.diagnosis) for visit in visits]
# counted_visits = Counter(tuples)
counted_visits = Counter((visit.doctor, visit.diagnosis) for visit in visits)
output = [({'Doctor' : doctor, 'Diagnosis' : diagnosis}, k) \
    for (doctor, diagnosis), k in counted_visits.items()]

print output
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dict as a class attribute to do the counting and then reverse the keys and value after:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Visit:
    data = defaultdict(int)
    def __init__(self, date, diagnosis, doctor, price):
        self.date = date
        self.diagnosis = diagnosis
        self.doctor = doctor
        self.price = price
        Visit.data[(("doctor", doctor), ("diagnosis", diagnosis))] += 1


lst = [Visit(date='2014-05-24', diagnosis='Z00', doctor='Smith', price=0),
       Visit(date='2014-05-25', diagnosis='Z00', doctor='Smith', price=0),
       Visit(date='2014-05-15', diagnosis='Z00', doctor='Smith', price=0),
       Visit(date='2014-05-24', diagnosis='K40', doctor='Smith', price=0),
       Visit(date='2014-05-20', diagnosis='K40', doctor='Smith', price=0),
       Visit(date='2014-05-27', diagnosis='K40', doctor='Jakobs', price=0),
       Visit(date='2014-05-21', diagnosis='J00', doctor='Abrams', price=0),
       Visit(date='2014-05-22', diagnosis='J00', doctor='Abrams', price=0)]

print({v:dict(k) for k,v in Visit.data.items()})
```

Output:

```
{1: {'diagnosis': 'K40', 'doctor': 'Jakobs'}, 
2: {'diagnosis': 'K40', 'doctor': 'Smith'}, 
3: {'diagnosis': 'Z00', 'doctor': 'Smith'}}
```

Comment: Hmm, that's an interesting solution